# Detecting when a PFFile is done fetching (Parse.com) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am attempting to fetch PPFile to an array of UIImages from Parse.com in a particular order.

The image below is a snapshot of my swift application's eight different PFFiles on Parse.com. (photo1, photo2, photo3, etc.)

[image]
My code is retrieving the PFFiles properly but are not being saved to my UIImage array properly in the order I would like. I believe my problem is that I am not detecting when the asynchronous call is done fetching data before I save them? Can someone please share their knowledge on the subject and guide me to retrieving PFFiles in order instead of fetching at random.

```
func loadImageArray(){
    let findDataParse = PFQuery(className:"MagazineContent")
    findDataParse.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "orQfF8MmVO")
    findDataParse.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        for object in objects!{
        if (error == nil) {
            if let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("photo1") as? PFFile {
            //let myServerImage = object["photo1"] as? PFFile
               userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("1. Found it")
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                }}
            if let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("photo2") as? PFFile {
                //let myServerImage = object["photo1"] as? PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("2. Found it")
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                }}
            if let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("photo3") as? PFFile {
                //let myServerImage = object["photo1"] as? PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("3. Found it")
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                }}
            if let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("photo4") as? PFFile {
                //let myServerImage = object["photo1"] as? PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("4. Found it")
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                }}
            if let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("photo5") as? PFFile {
                //let myServerImage = object["photo1"] as? PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("5. Found it")
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                }}
            if let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("photo6") as? PFFile {
                //let myServerImage = object["photo1"] as? PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("6. Found it")
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                }}
            if let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("photo7") as? PFFile {
                //let myServerImage = object["photo1"] as? PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("7. Found it")
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                }}
            if let userImageFile = object.valueForKey("photo8") as? PFFile {
                //let myServerImage = object["photo1"] as? PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    print("8. Found it")
                    self.images.append(UIImage(data:imageData!)!)
                }}
            }}}}
```

Comment: You are spawning all of the asynchronous tasks simultaneously.  There is no guarantee of the order in which the image fetch operations will complete.  You could start the fetch of the next image in the completion block of the previous or perhaps store the images in a dictionary keyed by name instead of an array and then you can retrieve the images in the order you want

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. Genius.